# What is the word for air we release while speaking a word?

Tags: single-word-requests

While speaking we release air, sometimes more than other times (while pronouncing the'f' sound). Is there a word for this air that is released?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Phonic respiration** (speech generation) is a type of controlled expiration that is used every day. Speech generation is completely dependent on expiration, this can be seen by trying to talk while inhaling.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exhalation)

> An early achievement in experimental phonetics at about the end of the 19th century was a description of the differences between quiet breathing and **phonic (speaking) respiration**. An individual typically breathes approximately 18 to 20 times per minute during rest and much more frequently during periods of strenuous effort.

[Encyclopaedia Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/topic/speech-language)

> **Phonic respiration** and Its impact on carbon
>   dioxide rebreathing in respiratory protective devices

[University of Wollongon](http://ro.uow.edu.au/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=4195&context=hbspapers)